# Saving TextView's settings on Orientation Changes - Android?

Tags: android, text, view, colors, orientation

I'm dynamically setting the Background color and text color of a textview component in my app, using a single options menu button "toggle color"

The problem is, as soon as the orientation changes the textview "forgets" what colors it was supposed to use...so it uses default and not those that were set by the options menu.

Here's the original function of the options menu option :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xxtt);

    if (Cflag) {
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        Cflag= false;
    } else {
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        Cflag= true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

^Cflag is "global" boolean, depending on whether true/false the function sets the textviews color. (If it's black on white, it sets it to white text on black background...and vice-versa)

After doing a little research, Here are the extra functions I modified :
Since on orientation change, the app pauses and resumes, I modified onResume to independently change the color according to the variable Cflag.

And also the OnCofigChange, to update the colors if and when the orientation changes. I've tried using both these functions , and I've tried using them one at a time. Nothing helped.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {


    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xxtt);


     if (Cflag) {
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        } else {
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

        }
     super.onResume();
}


public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xxtt);
     if (Cflag) {
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        } else {
            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

        }

  }
```

I don't want to unnecessarily use a SharedPreferences object.

I reckon it's a matter of logic only,

If it's black text on white background(default) .... Press the option menu's option, It toggles to white text on black background .... Cflag variable is also toggled.

Now Cflag is constant, we just have to set the text color again according to Cflag.

But I can't get it to work: I change the settings in one orientation, and on switching orientation it goes back to default state(The one I defined in XML, black text on white background..)

What's wrong?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Save them in bundle

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean("CFLAG",CFlag);
}
```

and it will be restored in Activity onCreate.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   CFlag = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("CFLAG");
}
```

Comment: What should I save ? ... My boolean Cflag is outside OnCreate()... in the activity block... So it remains the same right ? But when I update it, it doesn't work.. :/ and that variable is all I need to set the colors...

Comment: unless you specify android:configChanges as kalyanpvs suggested on rotation activity is killed and new is created. so CFlag will have default value. I have updated answer.